# Controls on video are not visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add controls to HTML5 video (full width video) but I have a problem, controls are not visible. I am using this example: https://jsfiddle.net/nfouvpe5/ here is my code:

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" controls>
    <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
      <div class="w-100 text-white">
        <h1 class="display-3">Video Header</h1>
        <p class="lead mb-0">With HTML5 Video and Bootstrap 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 75vh;
  min-height: 25rem;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

header .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Can anybody help me with this? What am I doing wrong? Why controls are not visible?

Comment: The overlay is keeping the mouse from being over the video.

Comment: @Taplar is there I way to put controls over the "overlay" ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are two things we need to address:

1) As mentioned in the comments, both `.overlay` and your header's `.container` are keeping the mouse from reaching the video. We can solve that by adding the attribute `pointer-events: none;` for both of them. Now we can pause/unpause the video by clicking it.

2) The way you're defining your video's size is by setting `min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: auto; height:auto;`. Calling `width` and `height` after `min-width` and `min-height` overwrites them (so they're not doing anything here). But the problem is actually that the controls are located at the bottom of the video, so they're hidden behind `<section>`. I think that's sort of a design choice, but you could set `height: 100%` and let black borders on the size of your video.

I'll keep looking for solutions like repositioning the video controls so you can keep the "cover" aspect of filling the whole screen with the video, but I think step (1) might be helpful already.